# How to create animating grid in Next js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js, libraries

> [image]

I have a figma design and I need to convert it into a webpage using next js. But I am facing a problem.

How to design this section, it is a zooming grid. How to create this effect of zooming grid ?

I tried finding a library for this but no luck.